# Pool two vectors together

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

I have two arrays like below: A from 1 to 4 repeated 8 times, B from 1 to 8 repeated 4 times. I want to shuffle B but with one correlation condition on the final Matrix. I don't want the same B value (lets say 1 1 1 1) to appear in front of more than 3 different A values. To explain this better:

```
A: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
B: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8
```

Acceptable shuffle

```
A:          1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
B_shuffled: 8 8 8 8 2 3 2 1 2 1 5 6 4 3 7 1 7 1 7 2 7 5 5 4 6 5 6 6 3 4 3 4
```

Unacceptable shuffle (because 8 in B appeared in front of A: 1, 2, 3, 4 (more than three times)

```
A:          1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
B_shuffled: 8 5 7 6 2 3 2 1 2 1 5 8 4 3 7 1 7 1 8 2 7 5 5 4 6 8 6 6 3 4 3 4
```

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1, 4 + 1,1).tolist()
A = np.repeat(np.array(A[::1]), 8).tolist()
B = np.arange(1, 8 + 1,1).tolist()
B = np.repeat(np.array(B[::1]), 4).tolist()
```

I used `random.shuffle(B)` but couldn't figure out how to add distribution logic to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add any type of distribution logic to `np.random.shuffle` and even if you could, your constraints aren't really suited to it. We're not stuck though. Instead of using a one-liner we can procedurally build up a shuffled array that satisfies your requirements.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

# start with a validation function to ensure we're doing the right thing
def validate_shuffle(A, B, max_A_values=3):
    assoc = defaultdict(set)
    for a, b in zip(A, B):
        assoc[b].add(a)
        if len(assoc[b]) > max_A_values:
            return False
    return True

# return a shuffled copy of B, or None if the operation failed
def pool_vectors(A, B, max_A_values=3):
    # shuffle a list of all of the indices in our array; our goal is to
    # assign B[n] -> B[indices[n]]
    indices = np.arange(len(A))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)

    # C holds our output
    C = np.ndarray(len(B), dtype=int)

    # this container tracks how many A values are associated with each B value
    assoc = defaultdict(set)

    # iterate through each B value
    for b_idx, b in enumerate(B):

        # iterate through each shuffled index value, starting where we left off last time
        for newpos_idx, newpos in enumerate(indices[b_idx:], start=b_idx):

            # check to see if assigning the B value to this index breaks our constraint
            if len(assoc[b] | {A[newpos]}) <= max_A_values:

                # this new index works but we might have had to go through multiple
                # indices that were rejected; swap the working index into the
                # front of the subarray of unused indices so it will be skipped
                # over on the next outer loop iteration
                indices[b_idx], indices[newpos_idx] = indices[newpos_idx], indices[b_idx]
                break
        else:
            # because we're building the list procedurally, there are random 
            # circumstances where we can "paint ourselves into a corner"; this
            # doesn't happen often but we'll fail by returning None for now
            return None

        # assign the B value to the output array at the chosen index
        C[newpos] = b
        assoc[b].add(A[newpos])
    return C

# test it out
A = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
B = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8])

while True:
    C = pool_vectors(A, B)
    if C is not None:
        assert validate_shuffle(A, C)
        print(C)
        break

# --- output --- #

[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]
[5 1 4 4 4 1 2 4 8 2 3 1 8 5 7 1 5 7 6 6 6 5 7 3 3 3 8 7 8 6 2 2]
```

Note that there's nothing `numpy`-specific in this solution and unless you're using it surrounding code you can easily replace the `np.*` functionality with vanilla Python.